# How to display a Html formatted response in delphi 2009?

Tags: web-services, delphi, xhtml, delphi-2009

I am getting this html string returned via a web service call.

I am having trouble displaying the html probably because of the odd format (notice how the opening brackets "< head >" show up as '&lt ; head &gt ;' instead)

This is my truncated html formatted response.

What I am trying to do is display this html page on a form.  But I am even having trouble getting it to open when I write the string to a file.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;......
...html......&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
```

Comment: For writing to files, I commonly use just a plain string list (`TStringList`) and add each string as a new line - then use its `SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile` functions to save/load any flat text file. As far as loading and showing the content, I'm not sure what you mean formatted, but for the actual page, the quick way is to use a `TWebBrowser` which uses the core of Internet Explorer. Formatting the syntax of the code is a whole other story.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, All I have tried to do is write the above mentioned string to a html file but I have not had any success viewing the file.  I just figured out why because the string needed to be decoded HtmlDecode(string).  Now its working..  Thanks

Comment: Trevor, please edit your question to provide information on how you're getting the HTML in the first place, and what you've tried so far that isn't working. The alternative (since you seem to have gotten an answer) would be either to post your solution as an answer to your own question (you can even mark it as the accepted answer after a short delay) or delete the question. Please don't just post it here and abandon it once you get a solution; it's not the way SO is designed to work. If you're going to use SO as a resource, please cooperate in using it properly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite - This string was returned to me through a web service call. I can edit my question and add the answer or just delete because it may not be very useful to anyone.  I'll edit my post to reflect that, hopefully it makes more sense now.  I will have time to post my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Trevor, thanks. :-) I'm still not sure exactly what you're getting, though; I can't tell if you've posted a garbled string or if you've garbled posting HTML in the markup here. ;-) You're missing a bunch of content in the middle (like the opening &lt;div&gt; tags).

Comment: @KenWhite the html in my string was being interpreted in the text editor as html so it was not showing I made one more edit.  Thanks  P.S. The html string was huge so I commented most of it out with ...html...  But I can add some more if it would make more sense.

Comment: You're getting XML, but are you getting it through Indy directly, or through `THTTPRIO`, or via some other methodology? (That's why I asked how you're getting the string, BTW, and for the code assigning it to your string variable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your input.  This is what worked for me.

```
 uses
 HTTPApp

 var 
 HtmlXmlText : String;

 HtmlText := HTMLDecode(HtmlXmlText);
```

I used HTMLDecode to clean up the odd characters to the standard formatting.

Answer (score 2):

&lt; and &gt; are [XML and HTML character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). For some reason (probably to return misformatted html) this web service(?) returns tag brackets <> replaced with &lt; and &gt;. If you assume that in returned <string></string> element &lt; and &gt; are used only as tag brackets you can just replace entities with proper bracket. If you can't assume that you need to parse string element text to obtain valid html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just writing code to deal with this string (and you don't have access to code that retrieved it) then the most correct way is to use an XML parser.

```
uses XmlIntf;

procedure blah;
var
    doc: IXMLDocument;
    HtmlText: String;
begin
    doc := CreateXMLDocument;
    doc.LoadFromFile(...);
    HtmlText := doc.documentElement.InnerText;
    // Your text is already decoded here
    DoWhatever(HtmlText);
end;
```